# Mencionar usuario que envió el comando con un bot de Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

He estado haciendo un bot de discord y he llegado a la necesidad de mencionar al usuario. El código que llevo por el momento sería el siguiente:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

"Codigo"

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def prueba(ctx, texto : str):
    # Escribe en la consola el texto recibido
    print('Comando de prueba ejecutado, texto recibido: ' + texto)
    # Almacena el nombre del autor en la variable "usuario"
    usuario = ctx.message.author
    # Formatea el texto en donde 0=usuario y "mention" es la mención a este
    await client.say('{0.mention} :ok_hand:'.format(usuario))
```

**Estos son los dos errores que me ha dado:**

> ```
> Ignoring exception in command prueba: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 902, in invoke
>     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 856, in invoke
>     await self.prepare(ctx)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 790, in prepare
>     await self._parse_arguments(ctx)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 697, in _parse_arguments
>     transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 542, in transform
>     raise MissingRequiredArgument(param) discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: texto is a
> required argument that is missing. Comando de prueba ejecutado, texto
> recibido: XD Ignoring exception in command prueba: Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 85, in wrapped
>     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "disbot.py", line 134, in prueba
>     await client.say('{0.mention} :ok_hand:'.format(usuario)) AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py",
> line 902, in invoke
>     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 864, in invoke
>     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "C:\Users\0.0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py",
> line 94, in wrapped
>     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'
> ```

Comment: El error dice que no hay un atributo llamado `say`. No es `ctx.send()` lo que quieres invocar en lugar de `client.say()`?

Comment: Como dijo @jachguate no hay un atributo llamado `say`, solo `send` con el que enviaras el mensaje, solo envía el usuario y será mencionado

Comment: Para enviar un mensaje tienes que usar `ctx.send(el mensaje va aqui)`. ctx significa contexto. Es un objeto que representa el contexto donde se escribió el comando.

Comment: Pero eso mencionará dira: Hola @usuario ?

Comment: Como puedes ver en el [changelog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating_to_v1.html#context-changes), `Client.say()` fue eliminado en la versión `1.0`. Ahora debes usar `ctx.send()` tal como te indicaron.

Answer (score 1):

Para que mencione al usuario, necesitarias:

```
await ctx.send(f" Hola <@{ctx.author.id}>")
```

Por ejemplo:

```
@bot.command()
async def saludar(ctx):
   await ctx.send(f" Hola <@{ctx.author.id}>")
```

Ah, y no necesitas poner `texto : str`, solo pon `texto=""`, y si el usuario no da ningun texto, no pasara nada, y si si da algun texto, aparecera.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ` texto: str` es la sintaxis de la sugerencia de tipo, en para el editor de código todos los parámetros de una función son `any`, si se quiere especificar algún tipo de dato concreto se hace con lo antes mencionado. Recordemos que eso solo te ayuda al momento de escribir, ya que python sigue siendo de tipado dinámico y no habrá excepción si le pasas un `int` donde debía ir un `str`